# How to join slices of rows to create a new row in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

In Python, i need to split two rows in half, take the first half from row 1 and second half from row 2 and concatenate them into an array which is then saved as a row in another 2d array. for example

```
values=np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])
```

will become

```
Y[2,:]= ([1,2,7,8]))  // 2 is arbitrarily chosen
```

I tried doing this with concatenate but got an error

**only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index**

```
x=values.shape[1] 
pop[y,:]=np.concatenate(values[temp0,0:int((x-1)/2)],values[temp1,int((x-1)/2):x+1])
```

temp0 and temp1 are integers, and values is a 2d integer array of dimensions (100,x)

Comment: Concatenate takes a list of arrays, not 2 or 3 separate arguments.  It's trying to interpret your 2nd argument as a axis number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.concatenate` takes a list of arrays, plus a scalar `axis` parameter (optional)

```
In [411]: values=np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])
     ...:
```

Nothing wrong with how you split `values`:

```
In [412]: x=values.shape[1] 
In [413]: x
Out[413]: 4
In [415]: values[0,0:int((x-1)/2)],values[1,int((x-1)/2):x+1]
Out[415]: (array([1]), array([6, 7, 8]))
```

wrong:

```
In [416]: np.concatenate(values[0,0:int((x-1)/2)],values[1,int((x-1)/2):x+1])
----
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

It's trying to interpret the 2nd argument as an axis parameter, hence the `scalar` error message.

right:

```
In [417]: np.concatenate([values[0,0:int((x-1)/2)],values[1,int((x-1)/2):x+1]])
Out[417]: array([1, 6, 7, 8])
```

There are other `concatenate` front ends.  Here `hstack` would work the same.  `np.append` takes 2 arrays, so would work - but too often people use it wrongly.  `np.r_` is another front end with different syntax.

The indexing might be clearer with:

```
In [423]: idx = (x-1)//2
In [424]: np.concatenate([values[0,:idx],values[1,idx:]])
Out[424]: array([1, 6, 7, 8])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try numpy.append

[numpy.append Documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.append.html)

```
np.append(values[temp0,0:int((x-1)/2)],values[temp1,int((x-1)/2):x+1])
```

Comment: Don't use `np.append`.  All it is a buggy front end to `concatenate`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need splitting and/or concatenation. Just use [*indexing*](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html):

```
In [47]: values=np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])

In [48]: values[[[0], [1]],[[0, 1], [-2, -1]]]
Out[48]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [7, 8]])
```

Or ravel to get the flattened version:

```
In [49]: values[[[0], [1]],[[0, 1], [-2, -1]]].ravel()
Out[49]: array([1, 2, 7, 8])
```

As a more general approach you can also utilize `np.r_` as following:

```
In [61]: x, y = values.shape

In [62]: values[np.arange(x)[:,None],[np.r_[0:y//2], np.r_[-y//2:0]]].ravel()
Out[62]: array([1, 2, 7, 8])
```

Answer (score 0):

Reshape to split the second dimension in two; stack the part you want.

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])
b = a.reshape(a.shape[0], a.shape[1]//2, 2)
new_row = np.hstack([b[0,0,:], b[1,1,:]])
#new_row = np.hstack([b[0,0], b[1,1]])
```